# Find and replace string in all excel files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in creating find and replace string macro so that it can do find and replace string in all files in a folder.

For example fofler  = `"C:\ifolder\"`
files list = `"*.xlsx"`

so far I can only do it for one file, I need to do it for all file in a folder

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\macro\test.txt"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "THIS", "THAT")

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: please show what you tried and where you're stuck

Comment: The very same trouble made me learn VBA 4 months ago from complete zero-level)))

Comment: You can help get an answer by providing more detail - what *exactly* are you having problems with? Do you know any VBA at all? Do you need to know how to loop though files in a folder? Open a workbook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Answer (score 3):

*As you actually have code that opens text files - not Excel files - I have followed the same approach*

Something like this where

1. `Dir` is used to loop through all [txt](/questions/tagged/txt) files in a specific folder.
2. Use the FileScriptingObject to read in all the text at once, make the replacement, then write over the file file with the updated text.

**code**

```
Sub  ReplaceStringInFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFil As Object
Dim objFil2 As Object
Dim StrFileName As String
Dim StrFolder As String
Dim SstrAll As String

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
StrFolder = "c:\macro\"
StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.txt")

Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
    Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
    strAll = objFil.readall
    objFil.Close
    Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
    objFil2.Write Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT")
    objFil2.Close
    StrFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: dear thanks for the code. As, I am new to VBA can you please help me where to paste this code and run. I tried it by pasting in VBAProject->ThisWorkBook. It is not showing any error while running but at the same time it is not replacing i.e. not working. Can you please help.

Comment: @guaravkumar place it in a regular code module. Ensure your path name has been updated (from C;\macro\ above).

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I am doing it for the excel files. I think this is the reason for the error: Input past end of file (Error 62). Can you please help me in writting the subsitute for opentextfile and createtextfile as used in the program. Many thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: @gauravkumar suggest you ask a new question :)

Comment: I have asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744968/find-and-replace-string-in-all-excel-files-workbook-in-a-directory-using-vba